# How to create a map dynamic in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I want to create a map like

```
{:a 1 
 :b 2 ;;in some condition
 :c 3 ;;in some other condition
}
```

But I do not know how to change a list like `[:b 2]` into `:b 2` in the map struct.

Here are some wrong cases that I tried:

```
{:a 1
 (if (is condition1) [:b 2])
 (if (is condition2) [:c 3])
 ;...
}


{:a 1 
 (map indentity (if (is condition1) [:b 2]))
 (map indentity (if (is condition2) [:c 2]))
 ;;...
}
```

All I tried will return a sequence not arguments.

Is there a way to handle without macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(into {} [{:a 1}
          (if (is condition1) [:b 2])
          (if (is condition2) [:c 3])])
```

This works because if `is condition1` is false, the `if` expression will return `nil` which is ignored by `conj` on maps.

Comment: What is operator `is`?

Comment: @Thumbnail I don't know, ask OP. vOv

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to go about it:

```
(fn [cond1 cond2]
  (into
   {:a 1}
   (map
    (fn [[c e]] (when c e))
    [[cond1 [:b 2]] [cond2 [:c 3]]])))
```

You would probably want to pass in a table of conditions tied to entry pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I think `merge` is a good option.

```
(merge {:a 1}
     (if condition1 {:b 2})
     (if condition2 {:c 3}))
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question which was to add a pair `[:b 2]` to a map, you can simply use `conj` :

```
user> (conj {:a 1} [:b 2])
{:b 2, :a 1}
```

Now, if you want to add a pair only when a condition (predicate) is true, you can have a function, e.g. :

```
(defn conj-if-value-is-positive [m kv-pair]
  (if (< 0 (second kv-pair))
     (conj m kv-pair)
     m))

user> (conj-if-value-is-positive {:a 1} [:b 2])
{:b 2, :a 1}
```

Next, let's say you have a list of pairs you want to add to the map depending on the the same condition, you can `reduce` on the sequence of pairs :

```
user> (reduce conj-if-value-is-positive {:a 1} '([:b 2] [:c 3] [:d -1]))
{:c 3, :b 2, :a 1}
```

`[:d -1]` is not added to the map, since it does not meet the condition.
As a matter of fact, the function `conj-if-value-positive` is not very generic and can be decomposed into separate steps :

1. filter the pairs on a condition
2. accumulate the results into the map

e.g.

```
user> (reduce (fn [m p] (conj m p))
              {:a 1}
              (filter (fn [[k v]] (pos? v)) '([:b 2] [:c 3] [:d -1])))
{:c 3, :b 2, :a 1}
```

In your example, you wanted different conditions on different pairs. This can be achieve by reducing over a sequence of `[[key value] predicate]`.